# Question on z-index on IE8 browser

Tags: html, css, z-index

Using Developer toolbar  on IE8 , on one page i see that the z-index  for a DIV shows as "auto",  I went from this element  to its parent hierarchy checking if some element has actually defined this attribute(z index) but I did  not see any element that has the css style attribute z-index defined/set.

I created a sample page where I did the same thing and it shows me the z-index as 0.

I have not defined my div or any other element to have zindex attribute but still it shows me the z-index as 0.

I am trying to find out why would I get the ZIndex as 0 on one page and Z-Index as "auto" on other when  it has not been defined in either of the pages.
Here is the sample of the css for that div.

```
.mydiv
{
position:absolute;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here but since `position: relative/absolute` triggers a new z-index stacking context in IE < v9 I suspect that's the distinction.

Comment: Thanks @steveax ,I added the position attribute as well but it still shows the z-index as "0"

Comment: It may be the parent element's position that determines it.

Comment: The parent elements of this element  are also showing the z-index as "auto" only.